# div not scaling to 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am following fluid layout where I have template which has header, menu and body.

```
<div  class="w100 h100">
    <div id="headerBox" style="height: 10%;" class="w100">
        <div style="width: 80%;" class="lfloat">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 18%; height: 80%;" class="lfloat">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
        </div>
    </div>
    ---------------body container here --------------
</div>
```

css

```
.h100{
    height:100%;
}
.w100{
    width: 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

where as when I give menu(child) divs width as 20%, my html page is getting horizontal scroll bar. but my parent div has width as 100% and my child div is not scaling upto 100%, I am forced to give 18%, whats going wrong here?

Comment: Add `html,body{height:100%;width:100%}`

Comment: i have added those to my body and html

Comment: try to give `display: block;` for `#headerBox`

Comment: @AldiUnanto i tried, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Add following css to divs

```
.block {

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ---------------html --------------
    <div  class="w100 h100 block">

        <div id="headerBox" style="height: 10%;" class="w100 block">

            <div style="width: 80%;" class="lfloat block">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            </div>

            <div style="width: 18%; height: 80%;" class="lfloat block">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            </div>
        </div>
        ---------------body container here --------------
    </div>
```